# Duplicate stsd entry in mp4 file

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am currently using ffmpeg to read video files and obtain the rotation code, size and etc.
However, there is this particular video file that is causing the error below:

`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe484026e40] Duplicate stsd found in this track`

`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fe484026e40] error reading header`

I am unable to solve this as there seems to be no stsd (Sample Description) for the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stsd is not "Standard Definition Description" It's "Sample Description".

If there is a duplicate or missing stsd, then the parser has no way of knowing how to parse the mdat. Hence the file is corrupt, hence its unplayable.

Comment: But I am able to play the video on a media player. Is it possible to debug it otherwise? Thank you

Comment: Different players are different. media player will just try to use one of the duplicate stsd. Other players will not. If you wish to debug the file, you will need to read and understand ISO 14496-12.